# My form keeps getting directed to nowhere upon submit b/c my forms action url already uses url parameters

Tags: forms, url, parameters, action, submission

Hi I have a Simple form that uses a get method to pass a value to the next page.  The forms action url is a url that already has URL parameters, so when i click submit I get redirected to a page that says so and so's url address dosnt exsist.  How can I use a url that already has url parameters for my forms action without being directed to nowhere?

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?ID=267" name="myForm">

<input name="text_input" size="9" type="text"><br>
<input name="text_input2" size="9" type="text"><br>

<input name="total" size="14" type="text">

<input value="UPDATE" type="button">
```

Comment: Can you have a hidden input field? Just put a field there with name "ID" and value "267". Hide it from the user with display: none and you're done. I don't like this style, but it works.

Comment: like the way you think...perfect answer...works fine...newbie here...this answer forces me to think a different way about url parameters...I like

Comment: How do I mark this ? as answered?

Comment: I just added an answer with the basic answer in the comment. If it helps, go ahead and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in a hidden input field:

```
<input name="ID" value="267" style="display:none">
```

You should probably do the display:none part in a CSS file somewhere though.